# How to do filtering in AngularJS ui-grid when using Grouping?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-grid

I just added Grouping function in my ui-grid, but then I found that the filtering function is broken. It happends in the official [tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/320_complex_grouping). In the example, no matter what you type in the filter box in the demo, nothing will change in the grid.

So for example, in that [tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/320_complex_grouping), I type Wyoming in the filter under the State header, I hope to see that only the first row of the data is showing in the grid, however what actually happening is that I can still see all of the rows.

Screenshot:
[image]

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you actually try expanding the rows?

Comment: I tried to expand the rows after enter filter text, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I fixed this today.  The filtering was actually working - the detail rows were filtered out.  But the header rows were still being inserted, and the data being aggregated, even though the rows weren't visible.